# SQL Database in VB.NET Application

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-express

I'm fairly newb when it comes to programming and even newer when it comes to database management and integration.

So I have a VB.NET Windows Application that uses a SQL Database. I use LINQ to SQL to fill datagridviews in windows that show table data and also use LINQ to SQL to save data to the database.

All works wonderfully however...

When I publish the application, the database isn't external as far as I can tell. It seems to build itself into the application so once the application is installed, the database is there, it views and saves data, but if the computer crashes or the application is uninstalled, all that data is going to be lost without a way to back it up.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express. I created the SQL Database in VS2010-Exp as well. I feel like there's something simple I'm missing here. When the application gets published and then installed, where is the physical database going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is running as part of the application.  If you wanted a separate, central database, you would need to have an instance of SQL server running in some accessible location.

Comment: This would be required of the user who installs the application? How do I tell Visual Studio how to do this? And would SQL Server Express be sufficient?

Comment: Assuming you want each instance of the application to share the database, you would find a server or workstation that you yourself could install on that each instance would be able to access (same network for example).  SQL Server Express limits the number of connections, so it would depend on how many clients you had connecting

Comment: It would only be 1 user on 1 computer. The database would local so each computer would have its own standalone database not dependent on anyone else, however if I need to upgrade their software or backup their database, I don't have a way to do that currently.

Comment: I'm currently installing SQL Server 2008 Express to try and do what you are suggesting to see if that will work. It's just a little bothersome that someone would have to install this for the application to use an external database file.

Comment: If it is 1 user, 1 computer I would look into other solutions.  Honestly, something like SQLite would probably be a more ideal solution, and you could keep the file separate from the application in the AppData folder.  This would make upgrading easier, and potentially eliminate your problem with uninstallation.  What does the schema look like and how much data are we talking?

Comment: I have 4 tables, the most rows of any of the tables is about 48 records. It's never going to be a super big database but will grow eventually.

Comment: Never used SQLite, checking it out now.

Comment: SQLite's site is very confusing. I click on a link to download and I got brought to a page with a bunch of source code links. I'm not even sure I'm looking at the right thing lol.

Comment: Though I'm still unsure how to tell Visual Studio how to use a database that exists outside of the application and NOT embed this one into the application?